# How to hide a DIV if ther's no value in that Content in a node--customtpl.tpl.php file

Tags: theming

How can I hide a DIV if ther's no value in that Content in a node--customtpl.tpl.php file? I have used a code something like this, but if hides everything weather it has data or not. Can anyone help me with this code?

I want to hide this "special-offer" div if there's no value in that field in drupal (this_is_a_drupal_field).

```
<?php
if ($content['this_is_a_drupal_field']) 
  {
  print "<div class='special-offer'>";
  print render($content['this_is_a_drupal_field']); 
  print "</div>";
  }
?>

<?php if(empty($content['this_is_a_drupal_field'])){ ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement needs a condition, ex: 'greater than' `>` 'less than' `<` 'equal to' `==` or 'not equal to' `!=`

The special **NULL** value represents a variable with no value.

So try:

```
<?php if ($content['this_is_a_drupal_field'] != NULL): ?>
  <div class='special-offer'>
    <?php print render($content['this_is_a_drupal_field']); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So basically we're saying if `$content['this_is_a_drupal_field']` is not equal to empty print...

Comment: Nope it Prints the <div class='special-offer'> without the content as well. :(

Comment: @UI-UX impossible, did you clear/flush the cache?

Comment: Yes this was correct and fixed my problem. It was not with the cash. this came from a field collection, and automatically passed the add edit links. I removed those and problem was solved. Thanks No Sssweat. AWESOME.

Comment: @NoSssweat You don't necessarily have to have a condition in an if statement. `if ($content['this_is_a_drupal_field'])` is a completely valid statement and is equals to FALSE if the given value has a [falsy value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), for example an empty string or array.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. interesting, thx.